# ASP NET Core App Docker Container opens in two different Ports

Tags: docker, .net-core, docker-compose

My application running in a docker container is accessible in two different port numbers, when the application is launched it opens in a aleatory port number, but the same application is accessible via the port number configured in docker compose. Can anyone explain me what is going on?

https://localhost:63060/ -> Aleatory port defined when VS opens the application
https://localhost:44349/ -> The correct one according docker compose

docker-compose

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  documentmanager:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}documentmanager
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://localhost;http://localhost
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=44349   
      # Do not create development certificate in an environment that will be distributed.
      #- DOTNET_GENERATE_ASPNET_CERTIFICATE=false
    networks:
      - doc_manager
    ports:
      - "51218:80"
      - "44349:443"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets/:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https/:/root/.aspnet/https/
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Document Manager/Dockerfile
  documentuploader:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}documentuploader
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://localhost;http://localhost
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=44335
      # Do not create development certificate in an environment that will be distributed.
      #- DOTNET_GENERATE_ASPNET_CERTIFICATE=false
    networks:
      - doc_manager
    ports:
      - "51217:80"
      - "44335:443"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets/:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https/:/root/.aspnet/https/
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: DocumentUploader/Dockerfile

networks:
  doc_manager:
    name: doc_manager
    driver: bridge
```

Docker File

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Unistad Document Manager/Unistad Document Manager.csproj", "Unistad Document Manager/"]
COPY ["StorageLibrary/StorageLibrary.csproj", "StorageLibrary/"]
COPY ["ConfigurationLibrary/ConfigurationLibrary.csproj", "ConfigurationLibrary/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Unistad Document Manager/Unistad Document Manager.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Unistad Document Manager"
RUN dotnet build "Unistad Document Manager.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Unistad Document Manager.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Unistad Document Manager.dll"]
```

My docker ps result

```
NAMES                PORTS
Document_Manager     0.0.0.0:51218->80/tcp, :::51218->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:63060->443/tcp
DocumentUploader     0.0.0.0:51217->80/tcp, :::51217->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:44335->443/tcp, :::44335->443/tcp
```

Comment: is the other port also exposed when running the docker compose?

Comment: No. Docker file exposes 80 and 443, Docker Compose maps  ports: "51218:80" and "44349:443". 44349 should be the only one.

Comment: I meant - what ports do you see exposed from the container when running `docker ps` for example

Comment: I added the docker ps result. Port 63060 is there. Probably Visual Studio added when launching the containers. Where can I remove this additional port added?

Comment: do you run docker-compose from VS itself or from the terminal?

Comment: I run from VS itself.

Comment: try then to run the compose stack using the terminal after you modify the docker-compose.yml file and the ports section to your wants

Comment: Many Thanks. I did. it's working now. I can access the Web APP using only localhost:44349, however I can't access the Web API from the browser using localhost:44335. I changed the Document Uploader - ASPNETCORE_URLS to 0.0.0.0. The problem persist via browser, but at least the Web APP container can access the API using https://documentuploader:445/api/v1/jobs. Just in case, you know why I can't access the API from the host browser, please let me know.

Comment: try and change the ports in the compose file. in the mean time I'm posting the answer

Answer (score 1):

The OP ran the application stack through VS and because VS uses random ports it didn't go as he thought it would. running from the terminal after changing the values appropriately fixed the main issue